# ReactNative Fusioncharts event not firing in iOS

Tags: javascript, react-native, fusioncharts, react-native-webview

I'm working on a feature related to Fusioncharts events, which is not working as expected, But Chart drawing and other functions working as expected. I found the below PR when Googled.
https://github.com/fusioncharts/react-native-fusioncharts/issues/48 But it's not worked for me.

Below are my versions and code:

```
"fusioncharts": "3.15.3",
"react-native-fusioncharts": "4.1.2",
"react-native-fs": "2.14.1",
"react-native-webview": "11.0.0"
```

````
    <ReactNativeFusionCharts
        ref={(ref) => {
            this.refChart = ref;
        }}
        dataEmptyMessage=""
        {...fcProps}
        type={chartType}
        width={this.width}
        height={this.height}
        dataFormat="json"
        dataSource={{ ...dataSource, chart: chartData }}
        libraryPath={this.libraryPath}
        onInitialized={(chartApi) => {
            console.log(
                'onInitialized - API: ',
                this.constructor.name,
                this.state.fullscreenMode,
                chartApi
            );
        if (!this.state.fullscreenMode) {
                this._chartApi = chartApi;
            }
        }}
        events={{
            beforeInitialize: () => {
                this.forceHideLoader();
            },
            initialized: () => {
                console.log('initialized');
            },

            noDataToDisplay: () => {
                console.log('noDataToDisplay');
            },

            dataLoadRequestCompleted: () => {
                console.log('lrc');
            },
            dataLoadError: () => {
                console.log('le');
            },
            dataLoadCancelled: () => {
                console.log('lc');
            },
            beforedataload: () => {
                console.log('bdl');
            },
            beforeDataUpdate: () => {
                console.log('bdu');
            },
            dataUpdated: () => {
                console.log('du');
            },
            realTimeUpdateComplete: () => {
                console.log('tuc');
            },
            chartCleared: () => {
                console.log('cc');
            },
            chartClick: () => {
                console.log('cclk');
            },
            dataplotclick: (e, a) => {
                Alert.alert(`You clicked on ${e.data.categoryLabel}`);
            }
        }}
    />

    {this.renderLoader()}
</React.Fragment>```
````

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version of react-native-fusion: "5.0.0", the component is revamped, events are working there : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fusioncharts

Comment: Thanks, @Zapdos13, I submit a support ticket and they advise me the same.

Comment: Great, hope the problem is solved

Comment: Hi @Zapdos13, Yes problem is solved. Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the guidance of fusionchart support service and @Zapdos13, I was able to solve the issue. Hope this will be helpful to someone who willing to upgrade the `react-native-fusioncharts`

All you have to do is following this guide.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fusioncharts

The instruction on their website seems to be not updated. So be careful to not to mix up with the old version implementation.

There is no need to run `fc-build-assets --fc-template ./assets/fusioncharts-tpl.html --fc-library ./assets/fusioncharts` or tinkering with assets folder in `react-native-fusion: "5.0.0"`

The issue is resolved once I upgrade the below packages with versions:

`react-native-fusion: "5.0.0"`

`"fusioncharts": "^3.17.0"`

`"react-native-webview": "^11.4.4"`

Also, required to install `"react-native-unimodules": "^0.13.3"` and configure it according to this guide https://docs.expo.io/bare/installing-unimodules/#installation (You may need to run `pod install` after the configuration and make sure necessary unimodule dependencies are installed)

Finally, Add update your `metro.config.js` as bellow:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('metro-config');

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig()
  return {
    transformer: {
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: false
        }
      })
    },
    resolver: {
      sourceExts,
      assetExts: [...assetExts, 'fcscript']
    }
  }
})()
```

Comment: Is it possible to make an expo, i've followed those steps, but it is giving me tons of error.

Comment: Really not sure could do that. Fusioncharts for React Native has a complex installation process. It's better to raise a support ticket if you have a license. That's how I was able to solve the issues.